# Can I alter the size of an infoWindow in a Google Map depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm currently creating a Spring Application for college that allows other students to see different things going on around town. I deployed the application on Heroku and the Web Application works perfectly, however on mobile things get a bit messy.

For example the phone version looks like this
[image]

And the Web Application looks like this
[image]

Is there a way I can make the info box smaller on a phone? I cannot find documentation about how to approach this online.

I currently create the `infoWindow` like so:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow2.setContent(events[i][0]);
          infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
        }
      })(marker2, i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or Find some default class for the box and add a `margin:20px;`
this will do the work.
OR
write a Media Query

> @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
>       width:100px;
>         margin:20px auto;
>    }

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. This approach would work if I added style tags to the infowindow and used CSS for the style sheet but as it is called from the Google Maps Library I'm not sure how to implement this. I've edited my question with how I create the infowindow. Thanks